# Azure VM: Cannot connect to MySQL server in VM from a public server?

Tags: mysql, azure, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench

I have purchased a Azure VM(Ubuntu 12.4) and setup-ed MySQL server in my VM . My problem is like when i tried to access mysql db from my local Azure Vm machine through Workbench its working fine, but when i try to access it from an external server which is outside VM i am getting some error.

I have opened Endpoint in Azure VM for port 3306, still its showing error.

Is there any setting i need to change in My Azure VM to enable remote access.

Error Message:

[image]

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Sorry.I have updated my Post with error message.

Comment: Did u solve this issue? I am also struck here